# Rails route path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So i'm trying to set up a basic client assignment system, but I'm running into an issue.

These are the paths I want:

```
assign POST /assign
unassign DELETE /unassign/:id
```

but I am getting the following from `rake routes`:

```
assign POST /assign
       DELETE /unassign/:id
```

The interesting thing is, when I output my link, the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/assign.1
```

Why isn't using a `/`? Furthermore, how do I make it `unassign DELETE /unassign/:id`?

---

#### routes.rb

```
post   '/assign'      , to: 'clients#assign_to'
delete '/unassign/:id', to: 'clients#unassign'
```

#### relevent haml

```
= link_to assign_path(client.id), method: :delete, title: 'Unassign' do
  %img{src: '/assets/unassign.png'}
```

I want to use `unassign_path`, not `assign_path`.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the whole `routes.rb` file?

Comment: you should use as: assign and as: unassign in your routes.rb. have a look at this section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
delete '/unassign/:id', to: 'clients#unassign', as: :unassign
```

Comment: this fixes my issue..  do you know why it was putting `.` instead of `/` though?

Comment: This may depend on the action in the controller. But could you try this also: `link_to unassign_path(id: client.id) #...`

Comment: @sircapsalot `assign_path(put '/assign', to: 'clients#assign_to')` is not expecting any params(no `:id` part in the path). In your HAML code you are passing an id to it `assign_path(client.id)`. As the route wasn't expecting any params it will treat `client.id` as `format` like .html, .xml, etc. Hence, the `.` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the beginning of your `routes.rb`

```
match   '/assign' => 'clients#assign_to', :via => :post, :as => "assign"
match '/unassign/:id' => 'clients#unassign', :via => :delete, :as => "unassign"
```

Comment: thanks @Vimsha, though I think i'll keep with the `post` and `delete` moniker's as well as ruby 1.9+ object notation